# IntelliJ + Scalafmt: Incorrect docstring indentation

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, format

For some reason, when using IntelliJ and Scalafmt 2.7.5, typing `/**` followed by [ENTER] results in the following sort of docstring:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the first asterisk has no indentation... Since I have "format on save" enabled, hitting [CTRL]+[S] results in a correctly formatted docstring:

[image: Screenshot]

It doesn't surprise me that the initial format wouldn't match up with scalafmt's, and that the formatting isn't really applied until saving or compiling (if that's enabled). However, the lack of indentation on the first asterisk -- even if it's only present until I save or compile -- is driving me mad.

Does anyone know how to resolve this without using the built-in IntelliJ formatter? This is actually tempting me to scrap scalafmt and just use the IntelliJ formatter for my team's project. Thanks :)

Here's the .scalafmt.conf for reference:

```
version = 2.7.5
project.git = true
preset = IntelliJ
```

Comment: Well, most people I know just assume that whatever IDE they use would format things wrong, and use scalafmt in sbt - either run `scalafmt` task manually and check formatting on CI, or run scalafmt on compile. Code generated by IntellIJ templates jest IME bad half the time, not sticking to either scalafmt or its own settings. So you will end up manually calling "reformat file" every once in a while anyway.

Comment: Please vote for the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10818